# Contravariance in practice - C#

Tags: c#, inheritance, contravariance

I read recently about covariance and contravariance - little code example below:

```
public class BaseClass{
    public int x = 1;

    public static void print(BaseClass objClass)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(objClass.GetType().Name + " " + objClass.x); 
    }
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass{
    public int x = 2;
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BaseClass bC = new BaseClass();
        DerivedClass dC = new DerivedClass();

        BaseClass.print(bC); //DerivedClass 1
        DerivedClass.print(bC); //DerivedClass 1
        BaseClass.print(dC); //DerivedClass 1
        DerivedClass.print(dC); //DerivedClass 1
    }
}
```

My question is - what contravariance give us in practice ? I know that I can pass object of DerivedClass as argument into BaseClass method (where parameter is BaseClass type) but what are the benefits of such operation ? And why when I pass DerivedClass object it returns me value of x in BaseClass ?

Maybe this is bad example for explain benefits of contravariance then I would be grateful for another example.

Comment: This doesn't use contravariance anywhere.

Comment: Wow - so there are misleading tutorial on the internet ;) But anyway - Can someone explain me why when I pass DerivedClass object it returns me value of x in BaseClass ? If it's nothing change why we can do that ?

PS. Sinatr - thanks for that link

Comment: You are confusing variance with inheritance/polymorphism.

Comment: Ok, I understand, sorry for confusing- but could someone answer me for my question above ? I would be very grateful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why when I pass DerivedClass object it returns me value of x in BaseClass ?

You are *hiding* the field in the derived class.  In effect `DerivedClass` has *two* `x` fields - one from the base class, one from the derived class.  Since the parameter to `print` is of type `BaseClass` the compiler will bind `objClass.x` to the field in the base class.

If instead you have a virtual property and an override:

```
public class BaseClass{
    public virtual int x {get {return 1;}}

    public static void print(BaseClass objClass)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(objClass.GetType().Name + " " + objClass.x); 
    }
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass{
    public override int x {get {return 2;}}
}
```

Or just *set* the base field to a different value in the derived class:

```
public class DerivedClass : BaseClass{
    public DerivedClass() {x = 2;}
}
```

You would see the results you expect.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helpful explanation! Now it's pretty clear for me!